# Locked out of my Galaxy mini due to "too many pattern attempts"

Tags: locked-out, pattern-lock

I have tried everything on the website and on many others, but nothing has worked for me. What should I do?

Comment: Does it ask you to log back in with your Google Account? What Android version?

Answer (score 0):

It will ask for your Google account, if it does not, and I think you have tried everything else, then you should do a Factory reset.